# Environment variable clientname gives no result on domain users

Tags: powershell, environment-variables, windows-server-2016, terminal-services

I am having trouble getting the expected result for environmental variable `clientname` in PowerShell.

On Windows 2016 Server through RDP session.

1. I run the request `$env:clientname` with a domain user and get no result
2. I run the request `$env:clientname` with a local user and get expected connected terminal Hostname.

This is affecting functions on apps running through TS with domain users.

Domain user result:

[image: Screenshot 1]

Local user result:

[image: Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 1):

Read this (very old) MS article

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2509192/clientname-and-sessionname-enviroment-variable-may-be-missing

It still applies.

Possible fix:

```
$sessionID = (Get-Process -PID $pid).SessionID
$sessionCLIENTNAME = (Get-ItemProperty -path ("HKCU:\Volatile Environment\" +  $sessionID) -name "CLIENTNAME").CLIENTNAME
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this!